# Output is not printing on screen after run chef-client -o 'recipe[deploy]' command on client machine

Tags: linux, chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe, devops-services

I'm facing an issue with the chef-client server, when I execute sudo chef-client -o 'recipe[deploy]' command on client machine it gets stuck on [2019-09-16T15:01:54+02:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 50389 
after that, no action is happening and output is not printing on the screen and when I press ctrl+c output is printing on the screen and recipe is executing.

Comment: This site is about programming-related questions. This describes a problem with using a specific software. Maybe you should ask in a specific support forum, e.g. https://www.chef.io/support/, or on a different site, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions Anyway you should add more details to your question: What is your environment? (software, hardware, network, configuration, ...) What exactly did you do? (all relevant steps) What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? (Where exactly do you see the message shown in the question?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like old chef-client process is running behind, kill chef-client processes and re-run chef-client cmd.